# Flutter Firestore - New query data after migration

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am updating a project and had to update firebase packages. But even after reading the documentation for migrating after mid 2020, I couldn't find how to re-implement the broken parts.

What I need is, after getting a document snapshot, to check if the document contains a particular key (which is boolean). If does, then assign it to a variable.

```
DocumentSnapshot document = await db.collection("users").doc("database").get();
if(document.data.containsKey(example)) {
bool key = document.data()[example];
```

Problem is:

1. How should be the proper replacement for `data()[whatever]` now instead of creating maps? The docs mention `FieldPath`, but how to implement in substitution?
2. There is some direct replacement to `containsKey` or a test needs to be created now?

Answer (score 0):

While looking for an answer to your second question I only found your post...

The answer to your first question is that you now access the value with snapshop.data['key'], instead of previously using snapshot.data()['key'].

If you by now have found the answer to your second question, I'd appreciate if you could post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the document into a map:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = await db.collection("users").doc("database").get();
Map<String, dynamic> map = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
if(map.containsKey(example)) {
  bool key = map[example];
}
```